# Type Error occurred when creating object: Mageplaza\\SocialLogin\\Controller\\Popup\\Create\\Interceptor

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, mageplaza

> Type Error occurred when creating object: Mageplaza\SocialLogin\Controller\Popup\Create\Interceptor

`{"0":"Type Error occurred when creating object: Mageplaza\\SocialLogin\\Controller\\Popup\\Create\\Interceptor","1":"#1 Magento\\Framework\\ObjectManager\\Factory\\Compiled->create('Mageplaza\\Social...', array()) called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/ObjectManager\/ObjectManager.php:56]\n#2 Magento\\Framework\\ObjectManager\\ObjectManager->create('Mageplaza\\Social...') called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/App\/ActionFactory.php:44]\n#3 Magento\\Framework\\App\\ActionFactory->create('Mageplaza\\Social...') called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/App\/Router\/Base.php:306]\n#4 Magento\\Framework\\App\\Router\\Base->matchAction(&Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http#0000000069d659a2000000005ddd7dd3#, array('moduleFrontName' => 'sociallogin', 'actionPath' => 'popup', 'actionName' => 'create')) called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/App\/Router\/Base.php:167]\n#5 Magento\\Framework\\App\\Router\\Base->match(&Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http#0000000069d659a2000000005ddd7dd3#) called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php:58]\n#6 Magento\\Framework\\App\\Router\\Base\\Interceptor->___callParent('match', array(&Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http#0000000069d659a2000000005ddd7dd3#)) called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php:138]\n#7 Magento\\Framework\\App\\Router\\Base\\Interceptor->Magento\\Framework\\Interception\\{closure}(&Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http#0000000069d659a2000000005ddd7dd3#) called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php:153]\n#8 Magento\\Framework\\App\\Router\\Base\\Interceptor->___callPlugins('match', array(&Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http#0000000069d659a2000000005ddd7dd3#), array(array('Mirasvit_SeoFilt...'))) called at [generated\/code\/Magento\/Framework\/App\/Router\/Base\/Interceptor.php:26]\n#9 Magento\\Framework\\App\\Router\\Base\\Interceptor->match(&Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http#0000000069d659a2000000005ddd7dd3#) called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/App\/FrontController.php:95]\n#10 Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController->dispatch(&Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http#0000000069d659a2000000005ddd7dd3#) called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php:58]\n#11 Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', array(&Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http#0000000069d659a2000000005ddd7dd3#)) called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php:138]\n#12 Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor->Magento\\Framework\\Interception\\{closure}(&Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http#0000000069d659a2000000005ddd7dd3#) called at [vendor\/magento\/module-store\/App\/FrontController\/Plugin\/RequestPreprocessor.php:99]\n#13 Magento\\Store\\App\\FrontController\\Plugin\\RequestPreprocessor->aroundDispatch(&Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor#0000000069d658ef000000005ddd7dd3#, &Closure#0000000069d658c8000000005ddd7dd3#, &Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http#0000000069d659a2000000005ddd7dd3#) called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php:135]\n#14 Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor->Magento\\Framework\\Interception\\{closure}(&Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http#0000000069d659a2000000005ddd7dd3#) called at [vendor\/magento\/module-page-cache\/Model\/App\/FrontController\/BuiltinPlugin.php:69]\n#15 Magento\\PageCache\\Model\\App\\FrontController\\BuiltinPlugin->aroundDispatch(&Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor#0000000069d658ef000000005ddd7dd3#, &Closure#0000000069d658c8000000005ddd7dd3#, &Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http#0000000069d659a2000000005ddd7dd3#) called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php:135]\n#16 Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor->Magento\\Framework\\Interception\\{closure}(&Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http#0000000069d659a2000000005ddd7dd3#) called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php:153]\n#17 Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', array(&Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http#0000000069d659a2000000005ddd7dd3#), array(array('mstCoreDispatch'))) called at [generated\/code\/Magento\/Framework\/App\/FrontController\/Interceptor.php:26]\n#18 Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor->dispatch(&Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http#0000000069d659a2000000005ddd7dd3#) called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/App\/Http.php:116]\n#19 Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http->launch() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/App\/Bootstrap.php:261]\n#20 Magento\\Framework\\App\\Bootstrap->run(&Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http\\Interceptor#0000000069d65958000000005ddd7dd3#) called at [index.php:39]\n","url":"\/sociallogin\/popup\/create\/","script_name":"\/index.php","report_id":"b584fcd99b453d794dbbdc28e9ff037b89934e899b5bcd5d003dea8eb974cdf3"}`

Answer (score 0):

It might be possible that the Interceptor is not registered when you installed the Mageplaza module: (especially when you are in *production mode*).

Please try to run these commands in sequence.

```
  setup:upgrade
  setup:di:compile
  setup:static-content:deploy
```